# scikit-learn OrdinalEncoder error: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have set a list of categories in my ordinalEncoder

```
noemployees_encoder=OrdinalEncoder(categories= [["1-5","6-25","26-100","100-500","500-1000","More than 1000"]])
mh_dataclean_encoded["no_employees"]=noemployees_encoder.fit_transform(mh_dataclean_encoded[["no_employees"]])
```

Afterwards when I call fit_transform method I get the following error:

```
could not convert string to float: '1-5'
```

I've followed some OrdinalEncoder tutorials and it apparently seems ok. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the dtype of your data like this

```
noemployees_encoder=OrdinalEncoder(categories= [["1-5","6-25","26-100","100-500","500-1000","More than 1000"]],dtype=np.str_)
```